# Templated base class initialization constructor fails despite exact class name match C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

In the following code, I have an item in the initializer list

```
ExtendHelper<Extender>::Type<>
```

that exactly matches a base class:

```
ExtendHelper<Extender>::Type<>
```

But the VS2010 compiler complains: `error C2614: 'Base::Type<T>::Extend<Extender>' : illegal member initialization: 'Type<Base::Type<Base::Type<Base>::ExtendHelper<Data> >::ExtendHelper<Data> >' is not a base or member`.

How can this be?

```
struct Base
{
    template <class T=Base>
    struct Type
    {
        template <class Extender>
        struct ExtendHelper
        {
            template <class U=ExtendHelper>
            struct Type
                :
                T::Type<U>,
                Extender
            {
                Type(typename T::Type<T> &rhs) 
                    :
                    T::Type<U>(rhs)
                {
                }
                Type() {}
            };
        };

        template <class Extender>
        struct Extend 
            : 
            ExtendHelper<Extender>::Type<>
        {
            template <class C>
            Extend(C &rhs)
                :
                ExtendHelper<Extender>::Type<>(rhs)
            {
            }
        };      
    };
};

struct Data { };

Base::Type<Base> base;
Base::Type<Base>::Extend<Data> baseWithData(base);
```

Edit: note that I had to add a default constructor to `ExtendHelper` because the compiler wanted one, but I don't know why.

Comment: My compiler spit way more errors than yours.

Comment: I think I discovered a bug with MS VS2010 C++ compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify that the nested name `Type` refers to a template. Literally replace all occurrences of `::Type<` by `::template Type<`.

(This isn't the only problem; there's another one with the constructor of `ExtendHelper` that I'm still trying to see through.)

*Update:* I think your outer `Type` class is missing a constructor. If you add the following two, it'll work:

```
template <typename U> Type(const U &) { }  // needed for `Base::Type<Base>&` in the constructor initializer
Type()                                { }  // needed for `base` in the example code
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example code is invalid, AFAIK. I had to apply the following changes to fix some of the errors:

```
--- nested.cxx.orig     2011-11-01 16:58:30.234375000 +0100
+++ nested.cxx  2011-11-01 17:00:13.781250000 +0100
@@ -9,12 +9,12 @@ struct Base
             template <class U=ExtendHelper>
             struct Type
                 :
-                T::Type<U>,
+                T::template Type<U>,
                 Extender
             {
-                Type(typename T::Type<T> &rhs)
+                Type(typename T::template Type<T> &rhs)
                     :
-                    T::Type<U>(rhs)
+                    T::template Type<U>(rhs)
                 {
                 }
                 Type() {}
@@ -24,12 +24,12 @@ struct Base
         template <class Extender>
         struct Extend
             :
-            ExtendHelper<Extender>::Type<>
+            ExtendHelper<Extender>::template Type<>
         {
             template <class C>
             Extend(C &rhs)
                 :
-                ExtendHelper<Extender>::Type<>(rhs)
+                ExtendHelper<Extender>::template Type<>(rhs)
             {
             }
         };
```

After the changes I get this:

```
g++ -Wextra -Wall -pedantic -std=c++98 -c nested.cxx
nested.cxx: In constructor ‘Base::Type<T>::ExtendHelper<Extender>::Type<U>::Type(typename T::Type<T>&) [with U = Base::Type<Base>::ExtendHelper<Data>, Extender = Data, T = Base, typename T::Type<T> = Base::Type<Base>]’:
nested.cxx:32:60:   instantiated from ‘Base::Type<T>::Extend<Extender>::Extend(C&) [with C = Base::Type<Base>, Extender = Data, T = Base]’
nested.cxx:42:49:   instantiated from here
nested.cxx:17:44: error: no matching function for call to ‘Base::Type<Base::Type<Base>::ExtendHelper<Data> >::Type(Base::Type<Base>&)’
nested.cxx:5:5: note: candidates are: Base::Type<Base::Type<Base>::ExtendHelper<Data> >::Type(const Base::Type<Base::Type<Base>::ExtendHelper<Data> >&)
nested.cxx:5:5: note:                 Base::Type<Base::Type<Base>::ExtendHelper<Data> >::Type()
```